# Objective C use char string in system()

Tags: objective-c

so i have this code

```
char processName[50] = {0};                  // init all to 0
printf("Enter the process to kill: ");
scanf("%s", processName);                    // read and format into the str buffer
printf("Attempting to kill %s\n", processName);    // print buffer
system("killall %s", processName);
```

put this causes the error "too many arguments to function 'system'"

Answer (score 3):

The function `system` takes a single argument, the command to execute. You will have to create a temporary string to build such command.

```
char command[1024] = {};
sprintf(command, "killall %s", processName);
system(command);
```